# Align normals to shape surface

Tags: bezier-curves, normals, conversion

I have several shapes like this as a curves. Sometimes with a whole in it:

[image]

As a next step I convert them to meshes. When i do this all my normals are looking in the upwards direction. But I want them to  all pointing outwards the shapes surface like demonstrated in this picture:

[image]

My ultimate goal is to use the normals in an outline shader in unity.

Is there a command in blender I dont know to solve this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Julian

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1: you can select the vertices that you want to change the normals of, then rotate them with Alt + N
[image]

2: you can add a Normal Edit modifier and assign an empty to control the normals direction
[image]